# Philips Semiconductor SAA7130 Video Linux Driver

Tags: drivers, tv-tuner, tvtime

I use Ubuntu 11.10. I need my Tv Tuner card functioning. Using lspci -vnn I figured out that the chip is:

**01:00.0 Multimedia controller [0480]: Philips Semiconductors SAA7130 Video Broadcast Decoder [1131:7130] (rev 01)**

I tried tvtime. But, it's all blue screen says;

**Frames too short from uvcvideo
  Cannot open capture device /dev/vidoe0.**

Can somebody help me please ? I looked through so many threads
but as a total newbie I can't figure anything.

Please Help me.

Comment: This question is about EOL Ubuntu 11.10. OP hasn't signed on in 5+ years and has abandoned the question. VTC as `not reproducible`.